# Rpy2 installation error

Tags: installation, rpy2

I'm on Linux CentOS. I have a custom install location for R (which I think was built as a shared library). I'm trying to install rpy2 using the command

pip install --install-option="--prefix=/home/user/python_packages" --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/home/user/Software/R/R-3.2.3/include" .

but I get the error

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lr_utils

I also get the message

R was not built as a library

which I don't understand as I did provide the enable-R-shlib option when building it.

Comment: Try without the `global-option` but with R in the PATH.

Comment: No luck -- it refuses to even find the include path in that case

Comment: You might have to share a little more about what is happening then (such as all messages displayed in the terminal when trying to install).